# vertical thin line on RTL - Outlook

Tags: css, email, outlook, line, html-email

how can I get rid of these thin vertical lines that appear on the left side on each text area?
it happens only on dir="rtl"
[image]

this is my code

```
 <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="middle" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        <table dir="rtl" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: 'open sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;" width="80%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign="middle">
                                                    <strong style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 35px;">
                                                        Title
                                                    </strong>
                                                    
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

I want to get rid of this extra thin line at the left side

Comment: @comunity any help on this issue.

Comment: As you have found, it's a bug that only happens on dir="rtl". Why do you need it? Since it's for Outlook desktop Windows only, and they have conditional comments that allow you to write something else just for it, you may be able to get around it. For example, if you use it for reverse stacking, you can in fact do somehting different for Outlook.